# How do you configure custom events to appear in an Adobe Analytics report suite?

Tags: adobe-analytics

In an Adobe Analytics report suite, I understand that `props` appear under "Custom Traffic" and `eVars` appear under "Custom Conversion" - but where custom *`events`* appear on a report suite is not so clear to me, and I can't find any good supporting documentation on this matter.

I've gotten as far as setting up a rule in Adobe Dynamic Tag Manager with an associated custom event (say, `event20`) - but after the success event is captured, it's not clear to me how this will appear on a report suite.

Also, do these even directly appear on report suites?

Comment: They are metrics on the reports. https://marketing.adobe.com/resources/help/en_US/reference/metrics.html

Comment: @MisterPhilip Are custom events metrics on the reports?  Where on a given report suite would I find the metric `event20`?

Comment: Yes. If you're asking where you can see the data, there technically is the custom metrics report where it shows you trended of many times that event has happened. There are many ways to pull this data though, it just depends on your reporting needs. However, this is out of scope for StackOverflow and better suited for Webmasters. Additionally, Adobe has a bunch of videos to help you learn (albeit the interface has been updated since the videos but it is still the same principle). https://outv.omniture.com/

Comment: @MisterPhilip Ugh - I found it under `Site Metrics -> Custom Events` ...  Can you please post your comment as an answer so I can mark it as answered?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Custom event configuration happens under `Menu -> Site Metrics -> Custom Events`.